# Orchard error to create home route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I had enable Aliases and Aliases UI module in Orchard.Then I changed my module as start up module using / to my module link then its works fine.Some by unfortunately I deleted my home route path in Aliases module then try to recreate my home route path again but orchard CMS does not allows me to create the home path again.When I recreate it gives me following error

[image: Here is error message that Comes]

Comment: If you save your content item and set it as the homepage it should be fine

Comment: I saved it try to make it home page but when I restart my site then it does not find home page and I have to manually enter name of page with URL to go to my pages.simply cms does not makes any of its content its home page either using Aliases or go to content item and set it as home page

Comment: Add the home route manually into the database. In the Orchard_Alias_AliasRecord with a blank path and RouteValues linking to your content item. But I have done what you have done before and saving content as homepage should work...

Comment: Thank Hazza ! But if you can tell me which route I should insert into db and make it home.Because Orchard_Alias_AliasRecord has following fields Id,Path,Action_id,RouteValues and Source.Can you tell me exact route ?